# Why don't FastInject tags work in my Flex/Air Parsley project when build in release mode?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, intellij-idea, air, parsley

I've got a project that I am working on that works fine when debugging from IntelliJ but when I do a release build (still in IntelliJ) and install the .air fil to my computer none of the FastInject tags seem to work.

I thought that this might be due to the include-as3-metadata issue but that does not seem to be the case. I have included all the metadata tags that I think I have used.

I have spent some time investigating this and have not made much progress other than getting frustrated!

I created a view that displays the logs created by spicefactory - but this seemed to fix the issue!
I tested to see if I could inject and of classes that are expected to be FastInjected, this also fixed the issue.

It seems that if I add any logging related code to the application the FastInject tags start working.

In fact, I have created a release air file [here](http://giles.roadnight.name/flex/FileImporter/com.pricklythistle.fileimporter_0.0.16.air). If I install this on a computer with Flash debugging turned on the application doesn't work. If I follow the steps [here](http://backroom.bostonproductions.com/?p=902) to debug an installed Air application - it starts to work!
If anyone else can confirm this behavior I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was simply a race condition causing an error in context creation that was not displayed in a non-debug player.

This exception never happened while I was developing the application and any changes to the application to add logging changed the initialisation order of the context and caused the issue.